# Implementing a demo using Validation in .NET FX 4.5

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, .net-4.5, .net-framework-version

I'm surprised that MS has implemented a new feature: Validation with INotifyDataErrorInfo

I have heard so improvement in this validation class, so I'd like to implement this one using WPF, but in MSDN I can't find an official sample demo to understand this interface.

If you have one, can provided me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be helpful.

[Asynchronous data validation](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/18/wpf-4-5-asynchronous-data-validation/)

[Asynchronous validation in 4.5](http://anthymecaillard.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/wpf-4-5-validation-asynchrone/)